# Prevent ampersand in ajax breaking when authenticating?

Tags: ajax

```
function authenticate(){

    var email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
    var password = '123&567';

    var ajaxRequest;

    credentials = "cmd=login&email="+email+"&password="+password;

    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    };

    ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'http://xx', true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajaxRequest.send(credentials);

    return false;
}
```

After calling the function the result is like:

> cmd=login&email="+"john.doe@gmail.com"+"&password="+"123&567";

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: I hope you realize that what you're trying to do is completely unsafe.

Comment: Because i send this to an "php" script. What is best way to do it if this way is unsafe? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `encodeURIComponent` to encode your password :

```js
var email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
var password = '123&567';

var ajaxRequest;

credentials = "cmd=login&email="+email+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(password);
console.log(credentials);
/* ... */
```

In your PHP, you can use [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Although i didn't provide all the information.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't provide all the information ? @Onasor

Comment: I mean the limited information. I didn't mention I use php as backend.

Comment: It was in your tags, i assumed you did. Either way, this is how to encode url parameters in Javascript. I'm sure you can find how to decode them in the tech you are using.